# Combining temp/lat/lon netcdf files via nco

Tags: nco

I am trying to calculate mean mean daily temperature from daily maximum and daily minimum netcdf files, so performed following tasks. But it is not giving me result. Could you please help me on this?

```
C:\nco>ncks -A G:\CORDEX\ACCESS1-0\RCP45\tasmin.nc G:\CORDEX\ACCESS1-0\RCP45\tasmax.nc
```

1 file(s) copied.
1 file(s) moved.

```
C:\nco>ncap2 -s "tasavg=(tasmin+tasmax)/2" G:\CORDEX\ACCESS1-0\RCP45\tasmax.nc G:\CORDEX\ACCESS1-0\RCP45\tasavg.nc

ncap2: ERROR malloc() returns error on Unable to malloc() value buffer when retrieving variable from disk request for 985675200 B = 962573 k
B = 940 MB = 0 GB
ncap2: malloc() error is "Not enough space"
ncap2: User-supplied supplemental error message is "nco_var_get()"
ncap2: INFO NCO has reported a malloc() failure. malloc() failures usually indicate that your machine does not have enough free memory (RAM+swap) to perform the requested operation.
```

Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

It clearly indicates that the RAM is not enough. You might need to free up some memory and try to run above command.

Comment: Tried it after keeping RAM free from other running programs, but does not work

Comment: The other options could be (1) Use CDO or (2) NCL . CDO will not give any problem

Comment: and NCL is easy to use as well. 
Instead of using NCO, use following CDO command
cdo expr,’sum=(var1+var2)/2;’ ifile ofile